# htaccess URL rewrite, Implicit single url transistion

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, white-labelling

I have written URL rewrite condition in MY htaccess file to achieve below. But I have done all the permutation combination to achieve below results via .htaccess file.

**White labeling**

```
http://www.Mayday.com/login.html => http://23.24.25.26/login.html#/varFooMayday
http://www.Hayday.com/login.html => http://23.24.25.26/login.html#/varFooHayday
```

also varFooMayDay and varFooHayday are constant values
And **login.html** should be actually be Implicitly **login.html#/varFooHayday** by using URL rewrite.

I need to write a condition for only achieving above.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mayday.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/kgbadmin/kgb/QTT/view/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /kgbadmin/kgb/QTT/view/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mayday.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ kgbadmin/kgb/QTT/view/index.html [L]
```

Pls can some one help me write this URL rewriter?

Comment: `Mayday` and `Hayday` are they two different domains?

Comment: From where are you getting: `varFooMayday`? Is this string always fixed?

Comment: May and Hayday are Two diff domains @RahilWazir

Comment: @anubhava S those are constant values

Comment: @abksharma The IP is also constant?

Comment: YEs IP is Constant for Two Domains in example, its WHITE LABELING solution @RahilWazir

Answer (score 0):

You can have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(Mayday|Hayday)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(login\.html)$ http://23.24.25.26/$1#/varFoo%1 [L,NE,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mayday.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/kgbadmin/kgb/QTT/view/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /kgbadmin/kgb/QTT/view/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mayday\.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ kgbadmin/kgb/QTT/view/index.html [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to redirect to a different domain/address, you will need mod_proxy.